# R system() command error

Tags: r, cmusphinx

```
system("C:\\pocketsphinx_continuous -infile C:\\temp_speech.wav > c:\\capture.txt")
```

results into the error

```
ERROR: "cmd_ln.c", line 604: Unknown argument name '>'
```

But if i paste the code directly in cmd all goes fine. Thanks in advance.
I am using windows8 64bit and R v 3.2.1.

Comment: You could perhaps try escaping the `>` character (`\>`).

Comment: That results into

    Error: '\>' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "" \>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because everything after `C:\\pocketsphinx_continuous` is interpreted as arguments. Your command is not run in `cmd`. See the help page of `system`:

> `command` is parsed as a command plus arguments separated by spaces.
>
> ...
>
> The most important difference is that on a Unix-alike system launches a shell which then runs command. On Windows the command is run directly – use `shell` for an interface which runs command via a shell (by default the Windows shell cmd.exe, which has many differences from a POSIX shell).

So, use `shell`